# How to change a hidden button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my project, I use `ajaxSubmit` to upload file. And i set `flUpId` init value is "flUpInt".

When i click fulId first time, i can uplode file to linux server with action.php. In action.php, I set `$flUpV="flUpChg"`, and this value return back.

I have tested in  `success: function(data)` that `alert(data.flUpV)` is `"flUpChg"`, and this value is correct. I use `$('#flUpId').val()=data.flUpV;` to set the hidden button of `flUpId` value. So `"flUpInt"` should be changed to `"flUpChg"`

When I Click fulId second time, I find  `flUpId` is  `"flUpInt"`, it is not `"flUpChg"`.The third time, fourth time...., `flUpId` is always `"flUpInt"`.

Here is ajax code:

```
$(function () { 
$("#fulId").wrap("<form id='fulfId' action='action.php?act=upFileCsc' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>");

$("#fulId").change(function(){
var flUpV=$('#flUpId').val();
alert(flUpV);


$("#fulfId").ajaxSubmit({
        dataType:'json',
        data:{flUpV:flUpV},
        beforeSend: function(){...},
        uploadProgress: function(){...},
        success: function(data){
         $('#flUpId').val()=data.flUpV;
        alert(data.flUpV);
        },
        error:function(xhr){...}
       });
      });
     });
```

Here is html code:

```
   <input type="file" id="fulId" name="mypic"><input type="hidden" id="flUpId" value="flUpInt" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the value you need to pass it to the `,val()` method as a parameter,  not use assignment.

So instead of

```
$('#flUpId').val()=data.flUpV;
```

use

```
$('#flUpId').val( data.flUpV );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is hidden you can not change it unless it is controlled by something else, something visible

Comment: I need a value to sign whether i have uploaded file, so I choose hidden button. If file is uploaded successfully, the value should be changed

Comment: Mybe cookie can help me